# Creating Campaign Member

Tags: campaign-member

I'm building a Trigger that looks at a custom Ticket object to see if the email address matches that of a current Contact.  If it does, I'm associating the Ticket to that Contact.  I then want to add that Contact as a Campaign Member on the Campaign the Ticket is associated with.  I have the code below, it's doing the first part correctly (finding any Contacts that match the email address), but it never creates a Campaign Member.  Any help is much appreciated!

```
trigger AssociateContact on Ticket__c (before insert) {
Map<String, Id> emails = new Map<String, Id>();
for(Ticket__c record: Trigger.new) {
    emails.put(record.BPT_Email__c, null);
}
for(Contact record: [SELECT Email FROM Contact WHERE Email IN :emails.keySet()]) {
    emails.put(record.Email, record.Id);
}
for(Ticket__c record: Trigger.new) {
    if(emails.get(record.BPT_Email__c) != null) {
        record.Contact__c = emails.get(record.BPT_Email__c);
    }
}
List <CampaignMember> campaignMembers = new List <CampaignMember> ();

    for (Ticket__c record : Trigger.new) {
        if (record.BPT_Email__c != null) {
        campaignMembers.add(new 
        CampaignMember (CampaignId = record.CampaignId__c, ContactId = record.Contact__c, Status = 'Responded'));


        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the final piece of the puzzle:

`insert campaignMembers;`

Do this right at the end, outside the `for` loop.

In a `before` trigger, you don't need to update your target object, but any associated objects that you create, you will need to update/insert.

This trigger could probably also be done in an `after insert` trigger, where you would have access to the object's Id.

Comment: Casp!  Thank you, I figured it was something simple like that :D